# Extract Image from PDF correctly

Tags: pdf, itext, pdfsharp

I have a PDF file that contains an image where this image is successfully displayed. When I try to extract the image from the PDF file using itextsharp or pdfsharp libs I get bytes, then decode them successfully (because there is /Filter/FlateDecode there). But when I try to convert these bytes to an image using different libs the exception occured (it looks like the bytes are actually not an image). As far as I understand the problem is processing these bytes, but the image in the Pdf is not corrupted because it is shown there correctly. [PDF is here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i341x25pjrninyb/file.pdf?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

The images are most likely stored in the PDF image format which is documented in the PDF specification.

It is rather simple to convert them to the Windows BMP format. But still you must convert them and add headers with the specific information from the image attributes from the PDF file.
In PDF a new image line is byte-aligned, in Windows BMP it is DWORD-aligned.
Don't forget to extract the colour table if there is one.